# Get index from selected Checkbox in DataGrid

Tags: asp.net

I am using DataGrid in Asp.net

```
<asp:DataGrid>
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateColumn>

            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkDetail" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="chkDetail_CheckedChanged" />
            </ItemTemplate>

        </asp:TemplateColumn>

        <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Name" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">

            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Name") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>

        </asp:TemplateColumn>
    </Columns>
</asp:DataGrid>
```

As you can see, there is a Checkbox inside DataGrid.

Everytime I check in checkbox, I would like to fire 2 events
1. Other checkboxes will be unselected (I can do it with JS - so it's ok)
2. Context will store DataGrid Name field like this

```
protected void chkDetail_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Context["Name"] = ??;
}
```

Because DataGrid doesn't have "Rows" like GridView, I have no idea how to get the Name from the same row.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
DataGridViewRow dgvrows = TrGrid.SelectedRows;
string c = dgvrows.Cells("Late_Time").value.toString();
```

OR

```
DataGridViewRow dgvrow = this.dataGridView1.Rows[index];
DataRowView drvrow = (DataRowView)dgvrow.DataBoundItem;
```

Comment: u r talking about gridview or datagrid?

Comment: My Framework is 4.5. It doesn't support GridView control

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

```
protected void chkDetail_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Context["Name"] = (((sender as CheckBox).NamingContainer as DataGridItem).FindControl("label_id") as Label).Text;
}
```

Your `sender` will be a `CheckBox` as the event is triggered by it.

Every control will have a property called `NamingContainer` which gives the nearest server control that inherits `INamingContainer` interface. In your case it is `DataGridItem`. And you can use `FindControl` method to find child control and cast it to appropriate control type to access its properties.